# regex to get first character in a string that isn't in ('a', 'b', 'c', '.', or ' ')?

Tags: regex

can anybody help me with a regex for this? I tried on and can't get the first character in a string. Thank you.

Comment: So, What did you tried as regex until now ?

Comment: How about the first match to `[^abc. ]`

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative character class:
`[^abc \\.]`

Comment: In most regex engines, there's no need to escape the `.` in a character class.

Comment: As a regex, you are actually escaping a backslash.  What your regex means is actually anything that is not A, B, C, Space, Backslash or Dot

Answer (score 1):

```
^[abc. ]*[^abc. ]
```

The last character of the substring that matches this regex is the character you're looking for.